# How to dynamically change android view text to capital and small

Tags: android

I am creating a custom keyboard only for my application,My requirement is to change the whole key text in my keyboard to caps/small (a,b,c,... to A,B,C,...) when I press on  "caps" button in keyboard.I tired

```
btA.setAllCaps(false);
```

To make text small

```
btA.setAllCaps(true);
```

To make text capital

but nothing is happening.

Comment: We don't know what is btA... You need to provide a lot more informations.

Comment: @Ben-J obviously, btA is a Button

Comment: @K.Dexter then I let you answer the question.

Comment: @Ben-J I did :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The initial values of `Button.Text` need to be in lowercase letters:

```
bta.Text = "A"
bta.SetAllCaps(true)   // -> A
bta.SetAllCaps(false)  // -> A

bta.Text = "a"
bta.SetAllCaps(true)   // -> A
bta.SetAllCaps(false)  // -> a
```

if this does not fix your problem, you need to provide more informations and code

Comment: The initial values of Button.Text need to be in lowercase letters,that is the reason :).Thank you :)